# Is there a way to obtain an embed link for a Google Drawings?

Tags: google-drive, google-drawings

I have a drawing in Google Docs Drawings, and I would like to embed a PNG/GIF of it in a web page, but I would like the embedded image to remain up to date with any changes made to the drawing.

Is there a way to do this?

It wouldn't matter if the image was only updated once per day or something, by the way. Ideally I would like something like this:

```
<img src="docs.google.com/drawing/png?docid=123456789123456789&width=400&height=200"/>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the **File** menu choose **Publish to the web...**. Choose an image size, then click the **Publish** button. Click **OK** to confirm and you will get a URL suitable for the `src` attribute in an `img` tag.

Comment: Has this been tested? I just found this and if it works it would be epic...!!!

Comment: Yeah this works amazingly! Exactly what I wanted!